# Using Xamarin Forms with MVVM my bindings don't update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am just learning Xamarin forms and can't seem to get this simple button to update the label here is my view code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:theJol.ViewModels"
             x:Class="theJol.Views.FindAJol"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:FindAJolViewModel"
             >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:FindAJolViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*, Auto,Auto, *">
        <Label Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding CountDisplay}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="Click Me" Command="{Binding IncreaseNum}" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

as well as the view model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace theJol.ViewModels
{
    class FindAJolViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        public FindAJolViewModel()
        {
            IncreaseNum = new Command(Increase);

        }
        public ICommand IncreaseNum { get; }
        int count = 0;
        string countDisplay = "Click Me";
        public string CountDisplay
        {
            get => countDisplay;
            set
            {
                if (value == countDisplay)
                {
                    return;
                }
                countDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        void Increase()
        {
            count++;
            countDisplay = count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works the only issue I am having is the label with the binding of CountDisplay. It doesn't automatically change it will stay the default "Click Me"
The only way I have managed to get it to change is while running the app in debug mode remove the binding to the label and retyping it which updates the app and it shows the correct number

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the private variable, not the public property

```
    void Increase()
    {
        count++;
        countDisplay = count.ToString();
    }
```

instead do

```
CountDisplay = count.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you that solved part of my problem, however, the application still doesn't update the label, it remains as "Click Me" until i go into my XAML code and remove the binding and retype it then the label updates and shows the correct number. I don't know if there is something wrong with my project settings maybe

Comment: are you sure that your setter is called and is calling OnPropertyChanged?  And try disabling Hot Reload too

Comment: And there is my problem the setter method is never being run I placed breakpoints and it doesn't reach OnPropertyChanged, I'm not quite sure why though

Comment: are you **sure** you are setting the public property?  If the setter is not called that is your root problem you need to solve.

Comment: that was the problem it wasn't public thanks for the help :)